# Unload classes at runtime

Tags: java, spring, jvm, osgi, loading

I need to unload classes during runtime. I have a custom classloader which is initialized during runtime. This classloader loads a newer version of a class. This class can also be renewed during runtime. In this case, I want to delete the older version of the classloader so that the old class and old classloader can be removed from the GC. The class I want to swap is a spring service. The change is working but not the deletion of the older version of the classes from the Heap.

I have deleted the old class from my custom classloader, the old classloader from the systemclassloader and set the parent in the custom classloader to null per reflection.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void findAndDeleteClass(final Class<?> clazz, ClassLoader classClassLoader,
        final Field classLoaderFields) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (classClassLoader == null) {
        return;
    }
    final List<VectorElement> swapElements = new ArrayList<VectorElement>();
    final Vector<Class<?>> classLoaderClasses = (Vector<Class<?>>) classLoaderFields.get(classClassLoader);
    for (int index = 0; index < classLoaderClasses.size(); index++) {
        if (clazz.getName().equals(classLoaderClasses.get(index).getName())) {
            final VectorElement vectorElement = new VectorElement();
            vectorElement.setPosition(index);
            vectorElement.setClazz(clazz);
            swapElements.add(vectorElement);
        }
    }
    for (VectorElement swapedElement : swapElements) {
        classLoaderClasses.removeElementAt(swapedElement.getPosition());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void findAndDeleteClassLoader(ClassLoader classClassLoader, ClassLoader systemClassLoader,
        Field classLoaderFields) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    if (systemClassLoader == null) {
        return;
    }
    final List<VectorElement> swapElements = new ArrayList<VectorElement>();
    final Vector<Class<?>> classLoaderClasses = (Vector<Class<?>>) classLoaderFields.get(systemClassLoader);
    for (int index = 0; index < classLoaderClasses.size(); index++) {
        if (classClassLoader.getClass().getName().equals(classLoaderClasses.get(index).getName())) {
            final VectorElement vectorElement = new VectorElement();
            vectorElement.setPosition(index);
            vectorElement.setClazz(classClassLoader.getClass());
            swapElements.add(vectorElement);
        }
    }
    for (VectorElement swapedElement : swapElements) {
        classLoaderClasses.removeElementAt(swapedElement.getPosition());
    }
    if(classClassLoader.getParent().equals(systemClassLoader)){
        final Class<ClassLoader> classLoaderClass = ClassLoader.class;
        final Field parentField = classLoaderClass.getDeclaredField("parent");
        parentField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object parent = parentField.get(classClassLoader);
        parentField.set(classClassLoader, null);
    }
    findAndDeleteClassLoader(classClassLoader, systemClassLoader.getParent(), classLoaderFields);
}
```

If I look with the **jvisualvm** into the VM the old classes have no instance and size 0, but are still there. The old classloader is instantiated.

I know that OSGi can stop bundles and uninstall them. The best case would be that I get an mechanism to unload classes like OSGi. Per reflection it isn't possible to get the classloader field from an class to set the classloader to null. How can I unload the classes?

Comment: the best way would be to use a memory profiler/heap dump analyzer and look for a path from a GC root to the class loader in question. Also note that it can take several GC cycles to unload classes.

Comment: You can try DCEVM with hotswapagent to reload Spring classes.  https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm, https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent

Comment: OSGi achieves unloading by discarding the whole classloader, which makes all of the classes loaded by that loader available for GC, assuming that no instances of those classes are still around and referenced.

Comment: If _any_ class loaded by a class loader is reachable, then the classloader and all classes loaded by the classloader are reachable and not eligible for garbage collection. So if you want a class to be garbage collected, you must make sure that there are no reachable objects which can reach any class loaded by the classloader.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but the problem still exists. Can anyone, who is compliant with OSGi and the uninstall mechanism, tell me where i can find the code part where this mechanism is implemented?

Comment: @JavaMinion There isn't really any code to look at. As BJ said, if all classes and the classloader itself are unreachable then they will be GC'd by the JVM in the normal way. OSGi's implementation of `Bundle.uninstall()` essentially just releases the reference to the classloader that it had instantiated for that bundle.