# How to compile and run Scala code programmatically

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect, scala-compiler

I have the following code and I would like to compile it on the fly and run it.

```scala
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

So far I have tried something like below:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object MainScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    val source =
      """
        |object HelloWorld {
        |  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        |    println("Hello, world!")
        |  }
        |}
        |""".stripMargin
    val tree = toolbox.parse(source)
    val binary = toolbox.compile(tree)
    var c = binary.getClass
    val m = c.getMethod("main", classOf[Array[String]])
    val params = Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")
    m.invoke(null, null)
  }
}
```

After `toolbox.compile(tree)` I am not able to get the `Class` object of the compiled code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the type of `binary` you'll see it's `() => Any`. So when you ask `.getClass` you actually get a subclass of `Function1`, which doesn't have `.main`.

Toolbox isn't supposed to be used like that.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/ToolBox.scala#L120-L129

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes

Try

```
val source =
  """
    |object HelloWorld {
    |  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    |    println("Hello, world!")
    |  }
    |}
    |
    |HelloWorld.main(Array())
    |""".stripMargin
val tree = toolbox.parse(source)
val binary = toolbox.compile(tree)
binary() // Hello, world!
```

or

```
val params = """Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")"""
val source =
  s"""
    |object HelloWorld {
    |  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    |    println(args.toList)
    |  }
    |}
    |
    |HelloWorld.main($params)
    |""".stripMargin
val tree = toolbox.parse(source)
val binary = toolbox.compile(tree)
binary() // List(Apple, Banana, Orange)
```

or

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val params = q"""Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")"""
val tree =
  q"""
    object HelloWorld {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(args.toList)
      }
    }

    HelloWorld.main($params)
    """
val binary = toolbox.compile(tree)
binary() // List(Apple, Banana, Orange)
```

or

```
val params = """Array("Apple", "Banana", "Orange")"""
val source =
  """
    |object HelloWorld {
    |  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    |    println(args.toList)
    |  }
    |}
    |""".stripMargin
val tree = toolbox.parse(source)
val symbol = toolbox.define(tree.asInstanceOf[ImplDef])
val params1 = toolbox.parse(params)
val tree1 = q"$symbol.main($params1)"
val binary = toolbox.compile(tree1)
binary() // List(Apple, Banana, Orange)
```

Comment: Does it support unloading classes?

Comment: @costa I guess loading/reloading/unloading classes (and ability/not ability to do that) is a function of a class loader ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095974/how-to-unload-an-already-loaded-class-in-java) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089729) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307149) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462279)). Runtime mirror is a wrapper over class loader (it accepts a class loader as an argument) and the mirror creates toolbox.

Comment: @costa I mean `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(classLoader)`. `runtime.currentMirror` is a macro for `this.getClass.getClassLoader`.