# How to compile and execute scala code at run-time in Scala3?

Tags: java, scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

I would like to compile and execute Scala code given as a String at run-time using Scala3. Like for example in Scala 2 I would have used Reflection

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe as ru
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val scalaCode = q"""println("Hello world!")"""
val evalMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
val toolBox = evalMirror.mkToolBox()
toolBox.eval(scalaCode) //Hello world!
```

If I try to run this code in Scala3 I get

```
Scala 2 macro cannot be used in Dotty. See https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/macros.html
To turn this error into a warning, pass -Xignore-scala2-macros to the compiler
```

How can I translate this code in Scala3 ?

Comment: Have you read Scala 3 metaprogramming documentation? Did you try something?

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes I did, but it is for the most parts incomplete and many of the links are broken. I understood very little, that's why I am looking for help. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Why would you do that? Runtime reflection should only be used in case there is no other solution, which is quite quite rare

Comment: Please report broken links to https://github.com/scala/docs.scala-lang/issues

Comment: What we are saying is that you should give us more context on the why you want to do that. Depending on the reasons we will be able to give you ideas on how to approach your goal with Scala 3.

Comment: @user3476509 Actually, your code is very close to working. It's enough to replace `q"..."` (a Scala 2 macro) with `toolbox.parse("...")`. See update.

Answer (score 11):

Scala 2 version of this answer is here: [How can I run generated code during script runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911801/how-can-i-run-generated-code-during-script-runtime)

In Scala 3:

- For example you can use [Li Haoyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871202/li-haoyi)'s [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/)

```scala
ammonite.Main(verboseOutput = false).runCode("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.1.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite" % "2.5.4-22-4a9e6989" cross CrossVersion.full
excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("com.lihaoyi", "sourcecode_2.13"),
  ExclusionRule("com.lihaoyi", "fansi_2.13"),
)
```

- Or you can try [Eugene Yokota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827/eugene-yokota)'s [Eval](https://eed3si9n.com/eval/)

```scala
com.eed3si9n.eval.Eval()
  .evalInfer("""println("Hello, World!")""")
  .getValue(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.eed3si9n.eval" % "eval" % "0.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full
```

- Or you can try my [implementation](https://github.com/DmytroMitin/dotty-patched)

```scala
com.github.dmytromitin.eval.Eval[Unit]("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.dmytromitin" %% "eval" % "0.1"
```

- Also you can use standard Scala 3 REPL [interpreter](https://javadoc.io/static/org.scala-lang/scala3-compiler_3/3.2.0/dotty/tools/repl/ScriptEngine.html)

```scala
dotty.tools.repl.ScriptEngine().eval("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "3.1.3"
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value %% "scala3-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

- If you have a `scala.quoted.Expr` `'{...}` (a statically typed wrapper over an abstract syntax tree `scala.quoted.Quotes#Tree`) rather than plain string then you can use runtime [multi-staging](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/staging.html)

```scala
import scala.quoted.*
given staging.Compiler = staging.Compiler.make(getClass.getClassLoader)
staging.run('{ println("Hello, World!") })
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.1.3"
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value %% "scala3-staging" % scalaVersion.value
```

- All of the above is to run Scala 3 code in Scala 3. If we want to run Scala 2 code in Scala 3 then we can still use Scala 2 reflective [Toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes). Scala 2 macros don't work, so we can't do `runtime.currentMirror` or `q"..."` but can do `universe.runtimeMirror` or `tb.parse`

```scala
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox // implicit 

val tb = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  .runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  .mkToolBox()
tb.eval(tb.parse("""println("Hello, World!")"""))
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.1.3"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % "2.13.8"
```

- Also to run Scala 2 code in Scala 3 you can use standard Scala 2 REPL [interpreter](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.9/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/shell/Scripted.html)

```scala
scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.Scripted()
  .eval("""System.out.println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.1.3"
libraryDependencies ++= scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % "2.13.8"
```

- Also you can use [JSR223](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr223/index.html) [scripting](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/tests/run-with-compiler/scripting.scala). Depending on whether you have `scala3-compiler` or `scala-compiler` in your classpath you will run Scala 3 or Scala 2 (one of the two above script engines: Scala 3 `dotty.tools.repl.ScriptEngine` or Scala 2 `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.Scripted`). If you have both the dependency added first wins.

```scala
new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager(getClass.getClassLoader)
  .getEngineByName("scala")
  .eval("""println("Hello, World!")""")
// Hello, World!
```

If you'd like to have a better control what dependency is used (without re-importing the project) you can use Coursier and specify class loader

```scala
import coursier.* // libraryDependencies += "io.get-coursier" %% "coursier" % "2.1.0-M6-53-gb4f448130" cross CrossVersion.for3Use2_13
val files = Fetch()
  .addDependencies(
    Dependency(Module(Organization("org.scala-lang"), ModuleName("scala3-compiler_3")), "3.2.0"),
    // Dependency(Module(Organization("org.scala-lang"), ModuleName("scala-compiler")), "2.13.9")
  )
  .run()

val classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(
  files.map(_.toURI.toURL).toArray,
  /*getClass.getClassLoader*/null // ignoring current classpath
)
new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager(classLoader)
  .getEngineByName("scala")
  .eval("""
    type T = [A] =>> [B] =>> (A, B) // Scala 3
    //type T = List[Option[A]] forSome {type A} // Scala 2
    System.out.println("Hello, World!")
  """)
// Hello, World!
```

- You can implement Eval in Scala 3 yourself using actual compiler

```scala
import dotty.tools.io.AbstractFile
import dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context
import dotty.tools.dotc.Driver
import dotty.tools.dotc.util.SourceFile
import dotty.tools.io.{VirtualDirectory, VirtualFile}
import java.net.URLClassLoader
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import dotty.tools.repl.AbstractFileClassLoader
import scala.io.Codec
import coursier.{Dependency, Module, Organization, ModuleName, Fetch}

  // we apply usejavacp=true instead
//  val files = Fetch()
//    .addDependencies(
//       Dependency(Module(Organization("org.scala-lang"), ModuleName("scala3-compiler_3")), "3.1.3"),
//    )
//    .run()
//
//  val depClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
//    files.map(_.toURI.toURL).toArray,
//    /*getClass.getClassLoader*/ null // ignoring current classpath
//  )

val code =
  s"""
     |package mypackage
     |
     |object Main {
     |  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     |    println("Hello, World!")
     |  }
     |}""".stripMargin

val outputDirectory = VirtualDirectory("(memory)")
compileCode(code, List()/*files.map(f => AbstractFile.getFile(f.toURI.toURL.getPath)).toList*/, outputDirectory)
val classLoader = AbstractFileClassLoader(outputDirectory, this.getClass.getClassLoader/*depClassLoader*/)
runObjectMethod("mypackage.Main", classLoader, "main", Seq(classOf[Array[String]]), Array.empty[String])
// Hello, World!

def compileCode(
                 code: String,
                 classpathDirectories: List[AbstractFile],
                 outputDirectory: AbstractFile
               ): Unit = {
  class DriverImpl extends Driver {
    private val compileCtx0 = initCtx.fresh
    given Context = compileCtx0.fresh
      .setSetting(
        compileCtx0.settings.classpath,
        classpathDirectories.map(_.path).mkString(":")
      ).setSetting(
        compileCtx0.settings.usejavacp,
        true
      ).setSetting(
        compileCtx0.settings.outputDir,
        outputDirectory
      )
    val compiler = newCompiler
  }

  val driver = new DriverImpl
  import driver.given Context

  val sourceFile = SourceFile(VirtualFile("(inline)", code.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), Codec.UTF8)
  val run = driver.compiler.newRun
  run.compileSources(List(sourceFile))
  // val unit = run.units.head
  // println("untyped tree=" + unit.untpdTree)
  // println("typed tree=" + unit.tpdTree)
}

def runObjectMethod(
                     objectName: String,
                     classLoader: ClassLoader,
                     methodName: String,
                     paramClasses: Seq[Class[?]],
                     arguments: Any*
                   ): Any = {
  val clazz = Class.forName(s"$objectName$$", true, classLoader)
  val module = clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(null)
  val method = module.getClass.getMethod(methodName, paramClasses*)
  method.invoke(module, arguments*)
}
```

([previous version](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/2e02055bc061e5b7c9421ba76e384013))

*build.sbt*

```scala
scalaVersion := "3.1.3"
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value %% "scala3-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

See also: [get annotations from class in scala 3 macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390113/get-annotations-from-class-in-scala-3-macros) (hacking multi-staging programming in Scala 3 and implementing our own `eval` instead of Scala 2 `context.eval` or `staging.run` forbiden in Scala 3 macros).

- See also

[An intro to the Scala Presentation Compiler](https://www.chris-kipp.io/blog/an-intro-to-the-scala-presentation-compiler)

[Parsing scala 3 code from a String into Scala 3 AST at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194436/parsing-scala-3-code-from-a-string-into-scala-3-ast-at-runtime)

[Scala 3 Reflection](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/siatmj/scala_3_reflection/)

[Help with dotty compiler and classloading at runtime](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/discussions/16080)

Comment: https://github.com/propensive/fury/blob/main/src/core/compilation.scala

Comment: Excellent, and thanks. But what if we want to create an `Expr[T]` from a `String` instead of just running it and receiving its calculated value? Is it possible to parse strings to typed expressions, for example load some file contents as a string, and then parse it and analyze it before running it?

Comment: Have you found a way @shvahabi ?

Comment: Dear @Joan according to my research it seems that Scala3 designers intentionally dropped this capability from meta programming design agenda (e.g. see https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/compatibility-required-for-migration-from-scala2-macro/5100/2 from Professor Odersky). Such design philosophy is justified by the fact that creating interpreters which only accepts special Scala3 code snippet string and disregard other valid snippets should be done per application requirements and hence is a developer task because it includes many per application design decisions.

Comment: On the other side, being capable of creating expressions from any arbitrary valid Scala3 snippet string, reduces readability and degrades scalability. Anyway you can create an interpreter large enough to embrace whole Scala3 language constructs, if your application requirements dictates. Scala3 designers only provided infrastructures to systematically embed string interpreters of intended subset of Scala3 language constructs, since merely no real world application may need to embed a whole Scala3 language interpreter.