# scala 3 macro: get class properties

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

i want to writing a macro to get property names of a class.
but can not use `Symbol` module in quoted statement. i receive blow error...

```
inline def getProps(inline className: String): Iterable[String] = ${ getPropsImpl('className) }
private def getPropsImpl(className: Expr[String])(using Quotes): Expr[Iterable[String]] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val props = '{
    Symbol.classSymbol($className).fieldMembers.map(_.name) // error access to parameter x$2 from 
  }                                                            wrong staging level:
  props                                                        - the definition is at level 0,
}                                                              - but the access is at level 1.
```

Comment: Rather pass the class as type parameter

Comment: but i need's process the `Symbol`s of class properties.

Comment: One more reason to ...

Comment: in this sample i get only name of properties, but i also want get more info about properties like it's type(by `propertySymbol.tree match ...`, that can't get that from `Class[?]` object (because `Class[?]` not contains type args) @cchantep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are compile time and runtime of macros. And there are compile time and runtime of main code. The runtime of macros is the compile time of main code.

```
def getPropsImpl... = 
  '{ Symbol.classSymbol($className).fieldMembers.map(_.name) }
  ...
```

is incorrect because what Scala 3 macros do is transforming trees into trees (i.e. `Expr`s into `Expr`s, `Expr` is a wrapper over a tree) (*). The tree

```
Symbol.classSymbol($className).fieldMembers.map(_.name)
```

will make no sense inside the scope of application site. `Symbol`, `Symbol.classSymbol` etc. make sense here, inside the scope of macro.

```
def getPropsImpl... = 
  Symbol.classSymbol(className).fieldMembers.map(_.name)
  ...
```

would be also incorrect because `className` as a value doesn't exist yet, it's just a tree now.

I guess correct is with `.valueOrAbort`

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def getProps(inline className: String): Iterable[String] = ${getPropsImpl('className)}

def getPropsImpl(className: Expr[String])(using Quotes): Expr[Iterable[String]] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*

  Expr.ofSeq(
    Symbol.classSymbol(className.valueOrAbort).fieldMembers.map(s =>
      Literal(StringConstant(s.name)).asExprOf[String]
    )
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
// in other file
getProps("mypackage.App.A") //ArraySeq(s, i)

// in other subproject
package mypackage
object App {
  case class A(i: Int, s: String)
}
```

(*)  Scala 2 macros can do more with `c.eval`. In Scala 3 there is similar [thing](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/staging.html) `staging.run` but it's [forbidden](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#scope-extrusion) in macros.

---

Actually, `c.eval` (or forbidden `staging.run`) can be emulated in Scala 3 too

[get annotations from class in scala 3 macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390113/get-annotations-from-class-in-scala-3-macros)