# How to compile code from an external file at runtime in Scala3?

Tags: scala, scala-3, scala-compiler, external-dependencies

I have the same question as [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874281/scala-how-to-compile-code-from-an-external-file-at-runtime), but I want to achieve this in Scala 3. I have searched for the libraries used in the first answer for Scala 3, but I couldn't find them. How can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945320/how-to-compile-and-execute-scala-code-at-run-time-in-scala3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390113/get-annotations-from-class-in-scala-3-macros It's compiling and executing from a string but it's not difficult to read a string from an external file.